# Why sharing optimal costs is so important in optimality?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

I understand the *strong duality* theorem:

*A linear program that has an optimal solution, also has a dual problem.  That dual problem also has an optimal solution with an optimal cost equal to that of the original linear program*

What I don't understand is, why is sharing the same optimal cost such a big deal?  I would have thought that sharing the same minimizer/optimal point would be worth noting, because then the solution vector of one (the primal or the dual) can be used for the other.  But, I do not understand why sharing the same optimal cost is worth noting....what am I missing out on big here?

thanks you.

Comment: Your view here seems precisely backwards. A problem that shares exactly the same minimizer/optimal point isn't a _dual problem_ at all, it's an _equivalent problem_. For example, I could just multiply the objective vector by 2 and get a "different" problem with the same minimizer.
Or, I can take a model, swap its right-hand vector and objective vector, transpose its coefficients, swap some inequalities and equations, and swap the sense (maximize/minimize) of the objective, andd _still_ arrive at the same optimal cost.

Doesn't the second idea seem far more interesting?

Comment: I can actually see how having, in your words, a "different problem with the same minimizer" would be very useful.  Then you could *pick* which one to solve, get the minimizer, and compute the optimal cost for *either* of the two problems using the same minimizer.  In optimization, usually computing the optimal cost is easy once you have the minimizer - just plug in the numbers.  It's finding the minimizer that is expensive.  Since the minimizer is what actually gets implemented, if I can find the minimizer an alternative way, and then use that - that'd be very useful.

Comment: So @MichaelGrant isn't an equivalent problem more useful than a dual problem?  I'm struggling to think of good use cases for the dual.  Thank ou.

Comment: Interesting. I mean, I can't think of a reason why an equivalent problem would be _more_ useful. I mean, one I've solved a problem, I've solved its equivalent, so the equivalent really adds nothing to my understanding. The dual problem *does* provide additional information, such as sensitivity analysis/

Comment: yes, and it also provides a lower bound...if I understand correctly.    If you can formulate a well-formed answer, I'll accept.  This would be for the benefit of the community - not just me.  my grad school colleagues are also unable to wrap their mind around this.

Comment: I'm still confused...@MichaelGrant could you provide an answer?